# INotifyPropertyChanged interface bug in vb.net and winforms?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I've created a small project in vb.net with a class and the INotifypropertyChanged interface. The properties from the class bound to text boxes in the main form.

Everything is working fine, but there is one big problem. If I change one property by entering a new value in the text box, the getter of all other properties in the same class firing to. If I enter values manually, that's no issue, but if I have external changes - like timer updates - no entering is possible anymore. The cursor in all text boxes flickering, because the external changed property is fires every time.

Why, I mean, this is a bug? I've built the same application and functions in WPF and C#. And if I change a property, only the getter of this property firing - not all other in the same class. To reproduce this issue, I’ve created a small application on GitHub.

Link to the GitHub Repo: [Link](https://github.com/mrinvestment/INotifyPropertyChangedBug/tree/main/INotifyPropertyChangedBug)

[image: GIF Record from the issue]

The issue: It's not possible to enter a value in the Double Number text box, because the cursor is flickering and no enter is possible.

Comment: You may find a quite common recommendation reading VB.Net posts: set `Option Strict On`. Possibly, as the default setting for all new Project. -- You have conversion issues, since you're binding numeric values to properties of Type String. Change all of your class Properties to this Type and try again. Note that the Binding you add provides `Parse` and `Format` events, which are used to convert values of different Types, back and forth. For example, an empty or null string doesn't convert well to Decimal.

Comment: In any case, changing a Property Value in a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't trigger cascading events not does call the setter of other Properties. That's just what you think it's happening. You can add `Console.WriteLine([The Property Name])` in the `OnPropertyChanged` method to see what properties raise notifications at any time.

Comment: Dear @Jimi, thanks for your help. Ok - you mean this flickering is caused by the conversion from decimal and string? And should I set your suggested option "strict on"? Thanks!

Comment: Setting Option Strict to `On` won't solve the issue, but it lets you see where problems may arise due to e.g, implicit conversions, which may not resolve well or as you *hope* they will. This is one of those cases. -- Another thing you may see in these implementations, is the value check in the setter of properties. Something like `if ([backing Field] != value {[backing Field] = value; PropertyChanged(...); })`

Comment: I believe your issue is actually related to the data binding and not `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When one property is changed, all the bound properties are automatically read. So by changing the random number on a timer, the double number gets read every time that change occurs. You are manually entering data while field is being refreshed with the current property data.

Comment: @Anu6is That's true, but just because formatting is involved. Some values cannot be parsed to Decimal (since this is the Type of the source Property). Hence the TextBox.Text is replaced when a validation error occurs (not matter what the Validation status of the Control or the Binding is). If the source Property Type is `String`, no formatting is performed, hence there's no change in the Text. Or, you have to Format the Decimal and Parse the string content *manually*.

Comment: Thanks for you comments and help! 

Ok maybe the conversion is the problem, i will try you suggestions. 

But the same issue with the flickering cursor occurs when i use a richtextbox and not a normal textbox … thats tricky to.

Comment: Hello @Jimi , i ve tried your solution with the option "strict on". But the cursor is flickering again, and it's not possible to enter a decimal value in the text box ... 

Do you have another ideas to solve this? 

I think all of you guys are rights - that's no INotifyPropertyChanged error, it's a data binding error ... :-S